# Eliminate linux version dependency

Tags: linux

I have zipped software. How can I import dependencies into this zip file so that the software can run on different Linux versions? For example, it requires gcc5, but on some linux gcc4.8 is the latest version. How about if I compiled this and put it into my software? I want to eliminate operating system dependency. How can i do that ?

Comment: Don't.  Cluttering packaged software with extraneous crap is a PITA for everyone.  Instead, document what your software requires.  and/or modify it so that it can be compiled with any version of gcc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flatpak, snap or appimage:

https://ostechnix.com/linux-package-managers-compared-appimage-vs-snap-vs-flatpak/

https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/Similar-projects#comparison

https://askubuntu.com/questions/866511/what-are-the-differences-between-snaps-appimage-flatpak-and-others

Alternatively you could link statically but it's only possible if you're linking with libraries which are available under licenses other than GPL.